# Auto write content c# string

Tags: c#, .net, automation

Right guys here is my problem, I am trying to make a autospinner using a database of words to match agasint words in a string.How can i add brackets around each word within a string along with the | and the opposite word..

for example if I have a var called theString with the string "Hello world my name is mintuz" How could I add { } around each word along with the or bracket and a possible word read from the database. so it reads...

"{Hello | Hi} {world | Univerise} {my} {name | ID} {is | may be } {mintuz}"

I was thinking maybe find the length of the string and everytime a space appears in the text, add a } before and a { after the space character. Im not too sure about the | and the possible word. Any ideas would be greatful thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be my (more imperative) attempt.

```
static string GenerateGrouping(string str)
{
    var grouped = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var word in str.Split(' '))
    {
        var fetchedWord = FetchMatchingWordFromDatabase(word);
        grouped.Append("{" + word + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fetchedWord) ? string.Empty : " | " + fetchedWord) + "} ");
    }
    return grouped.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would start by splitting the string by `' '`

so

```
string[] stringArr = string.Split(' '); //up to you to sanitize it, remove dbl spaces etc...

//then I would use LINQ goodness and select a formatted string

string finalValue = String.Join(" ",stringArr.Select(x=> string.Format("{{0} | {1}}",x, MethodToGetOppositeFromDB(x))).ToArray());
```

Comment: In case there is no matching word, your method will append redundant pipe symbols. Other than that, I love Linq expessions :)

Comment: oO, then we'll make a wrapper method for the string.format that can return string.Empty haha :) geez man LINQ makes coding a lil' easier!